# Retrieve Data from data base to html form on button CLICK

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I am actually starting my newest codes with HTML/PHP .
I am searching for retrieving data (list of persons) from mysql Data Base, displaying it into html table, then when I will clik on button "edit" it will show me in another page the details of the selected person like this :

[image: List of persons]

It works fine for all the rows expects the firt row of the table.
Any help please !!!
there is my code :

```html
<table border = 1> 
    <caption> Liste des personnes </caption> 
    <tr>
        <th>id </th>
        <th>nom</th>
        <th>prenom</th>
        <th>date Naissance</th>
        <th>sexe</th>
        <th>ville</th>
        <th>comptence</th>
        <th>photo</th>
    </tr>
    <?php while ($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)){ ?> 
    <tr>
        <td> <?= $obj->id ?> </td>
        <td><?= $obj->nom?></td>
        <td><?= $obj->prenom?></td>
        <td><?= $obj->dateNaissance?></td>
        <td><?= $obj->sexe?></td>
        <td><?= $obj->ville?></td> 
        <td><?= $obj->competence?></td>
        <?php if (isset($obj->photo)) {?>
        <td><img src="uploads/<?= $obj->photo?>" width =20 height = 20 >
        <?php } ?>
        <td>
        <form name="editPerson" action="edit.php" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=  $obj->id  ?>">
            <input type="submit" name="editer" value="Edit">
        </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: It's ``Féminin`` not ``Fémenin``, and ``Compétences`` not ``comptence``.

Answer (score 0):

#### Explainations

You can't have an `action='edit.php'` as you will edit a specific user, not all of them. You need to specify in your action what user you want to edit. And it is mostly done with the ID of the user. So you action will look like this `action='edit.php?id=1`. And so, your method would be `GET`.

In your `edit.php`, you will have a `$_GET['id']` variable that will contain the ID of the user to be edited. So you will have to first create a new query to search for this specific user.

You can then proceed on preparing the query.

```
$query = $connexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id');
```

And then, executing the query with the id from the URI.

```
$query->execute(['id' => $_GET['id']]);
```

And cast the result to a variable to get the user.

Then, all you have to do in your page is a little bit of refactoring from your previous page. Meaning that there will be now a big `<form>` tag surrounding your `<table>` tag and the `<td>` tag will now contain `<input value='<?php $user->id; ?>'>` tag for example for the ID. And your edit buttons will now be a save button.

The method of the `<form>` in your `edit?id=1` would be a `POST` method ot itself. So in the same page, you will be able to update the user. You can also cast the form to another page, like `saveUser.php`. Just be consistent from one solution to another in all your project.

```
<form method='POST' action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code

```
<a href="<?php echo "edit.php?id=$obj->id" ?>" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;"><input type="submit" name="editer" value="Edit"></a>
```

Instead of

```
<form name="editPerson" action="edit.php" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=  $obj->id  ?>">
            <input type="submit" name="editer" value="Edit">
        </form>
```

And get the id value on edit.php file by using $_GET['id'].
Example for edit.php file:

```
$id = $_GET['id']
```

Comment: Awesome! If it's working well then please accept the answer. Cheers!